# Can protractor test an already deployed Angular application?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am working on an Angular application that is deployed as a component within another web application. It relies on REST apis of the parent application. Can protractor be configured to run against an already deployed application or would I be better off using Selenium directly for e2e testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can. Look at the Protractor docs, they are shown to be testing the AngularJS site: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#writing-tests

Comment: I read this before, but it did not sink in until you focused my attention. The docs also show protractor can be run without requiring port 4444, which was my next question.